# Parsing URL to get the hyber link and store the hyber link in separate variable

Tags: java, android, url, html-parsing, jsoup

Hi I am working on URL parsing on jsoup. When I parse the URL I want to get all the `href`inside the table and store every `href` in separate variable. My Java code is here

```
String url=null;
    try
    {       

        doc=Jsoup.connect("http://livechennai.com/powershutdown_news_chennai.asp").get();           
        Elements table=doc.select("#table13>tbody>tr>td>a");
        for(Element link:table){
            url=link.attr("abs:href");
            System.out.println(url);

        }

    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My output is shown below

```
http://livechennai.com/detailnews.asp?newsid=18318
http://livechennai.com/detailnews.asp?newsid=18318
http://livechennai.com/detailnews.asp?newsid=18112
http://livechennai.com/detailnews.asp?newsid=18112
http://livechennai.com/detailnews.asp?newsid=18006
http://livechennai.com/detailnews.asp?newsid=18006
http://livechennai.com/detailnews.asp?newsid=17556
http://livechennai.com/detailnews.asp?newsid=17556
http://livechennai.com/detailnews.asp?newsid=17454
http://livechennai.com/detailnews.asp?newsid=17454
```

how to store every href link in separate variable or any other way is possible. Help me to get the exact answer.

Comment: What do you want to do with the links?

Comment: again i want to parse that links and get some value from it.help me to solve

Comment: Store all links temporary list, and again parse using Jsoup.

Comment: can you explain with code ? or example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a small snippet how to add the URLs from `href` elements to a `List`

```
List<String> hrefs = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://livechennai.com/powershutdown_news_chennai.asp").get();

    // more specific element specification, as in the question
    // Elements table = doc.select("#table13>tbody>tr>td>a");

    // less specific as mentioned by Jonathan
    Elements table = doc.select("#table13 a");

    for (Element link : table) {
        hrefs.add(link.attr("abs:href"));
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
// here you can process all hrefs
for (String href : hrefs) {
    System.out.println(href);
}
```

Comment: BTW those selectors are more specific than you need them. "#table1 a" works just as well. See http://try.jsoup.org/~x6V6plWZdtNisQCALCmOuRD2MjY

Comment: @JonathanHedley I didn't check that, as the question was only how to store the links in a list. But I updated the answer to include your proposed change.